# Springboot: Atributo con @Autowired es null

Tags: spring-boot

Estoy tratando de crear una archivo de validaciones para luego ser llamado en el controlador, por lo que estoy utilizando el Autowired en el atributo de la clase donde tendré todas las validaciones, para crear un enlace entre la clase que valida y la implementación de  mi modelo.

He estado investigando y he leído que tiene algo que ver con el componentScan ya que el Sprintboot framework no detecta mi clase por no tener anotaciones relacionadas al framework, por el contrario mi clase controladora si tiene anotaciones de Springboot, que es la anotación `@RestController`.

La clase Dao o Imp

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class RegCodeImp implements RegCodeInterface {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void storeRegCode(RegCode regCode) {
        entityManager.merge(regCode);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Boolean checkCode(String regCode) {

        String query = "FROM RegCode WHERE reg_code = :reg_code";
        List<RegCode> lista = entityManager.createQuery(query)
                .setParameter("reg_code", regCode)
                .getResultList();

       return lista.isEmpty();
      
    }
}
```

Luego intento utilizar el Autowired para tratar enlazarla desde la clase `UserValidations`

```
@Service
public class UserValidations {

    @Autowired
    private RegCodeImp regCodeImp;

    /*
     * El método donde lo implemento
    */
    public String testing(String user){
        return regCodeImp.checkCode(user).toString();
    }

}
```

Luego lo llamo en el controlador:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserImp userImp;

    @Autowired
    private RegCodeImp regCodeImp;

    private UserValidations validations = new UserValidations();

    private Environment env;

    @RequestMapping(value = "api/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public JSONResponse registerUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return new JSONResponse("success", true, validations.testing(user.getRegCodeUsed()));
```

Sin embargo cuando ejecuto los métodos de la clase UserValidations dentro del controlador me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Cannot invoke "com.system.imp.RegCodeImp.checkCode(String)" because "this.regCodeImp" is null
```

Pero si por el  contrario ejecuto los métodos de la clase que implementa el método desde el controlador el @Autowired funciona sin problemas.

La pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo utilizar la anotación @Autowired en un atributo de clase fuera del controlador?

Comment: Tiene la clase Utility alguna anotación? ¿Cómo es instanciada?

Comment: No ninguna, es instanciada por métodos `static`

Comment: Fuera del controlador y donde quieras, siempre y cuando tu componente tenga una anotación de componente de springboot, sea `@component`, `@service`, `@controller` o lo que sea. No puedes utilizar autowired si la clase no está manejada por SpringBoot

Comment: Que puedo hacer para resolverlo? No quiero meter toda esa logica en el controlador. Utilicé `@Component` en la clase utility y no me funcionó.

Comment: Normalmente la lógica no va en el Controlador, si no en un servicio. Un archivo `utils` tiene eso, utilidades. No la lógica principal de negocio. Si tu controller se llama `PojoController` haces un `PojoService`, lo anotas como `@service` y BOOM, ya puedes usar `@Autowired`. Y no tiene mucho sentido hacerlo `static`, porque las intancias te las manejará SpringBoot correctamente

Comment: Ok dejame probar con @Service.

Comment: Agregué la anotación `@Service` a la clase Utility y nada, tengo que leer más sobre @Service

Comment: En la implementación tengo en la clase tengo las anotaciones `@Repository`
`@Transactional` será eso la causa?

Comment: Agregué más código para que se entienda mejor.

Answer (score 2):

Como tal SpringBoot ya realiza el `ComponentScan` por defecto esto es así porque la anotación `@SpringBootApplication` es la unión de variar anotaciones como `@ComponentScan` `@EnableAutoConfiguration` `@SpringBootConfiguration` y para facilitar la implementación se creo `@SpringBootApplication` para englobarlas, como regla principal Spring Boot no es un producto aparte, es un complemento de la librería Spring que viene a automatizar y crear un marco de trabajo de cara a los despliegues, por ende todo lo que funcione en Spring funciona en Spring Boot es solo saber como se acoplan los components.

El error que tienes es porque a la clase `UserValidations` le agregas la anotación `@Service` esto la agregaría el contexto de Spring para ser Inyectada en otros componentes pero en la clase `UserController` lo que haces es instanciarla con `private UserValidations validations = new UserValidations();` al instanciar la clase de forma manual te saltas el contexto de Spring y por consecuencia la inyección `@Autowired private RegCodeImp regCodeImp;` no se realizaría  y `regCodeImp seria null`.

Solución: No crees una nueva instancia de `UserValidations` sino inyéctala como cualquier otro componente.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserImp userImp;

    @Autowired
    private RegCodeImp regCodeImp;

    @Autowired
    private UserValidations validations;

    private Environment env;
```